# Save data in variable php

Tags: php, variables, include, native

I have a form input data called input.php, and the data will be process in process.php,
how can I get data after the process?

**source code for form input.php**

```
<form action="process.php" method="POST" >
    <select id="selectbasic" name="time" class="input100">
    <option value="not" selected>-choose-< /option>
    <option value="m">Minut< /option>
    <option value="s">Second< /option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" name="field" id="time" />
    <button type="submit">Time </button>
</form>
```

**source code for process.php**

```
<?php if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
     $nmr = $_POST['field'];
     $time = $_POST['time'];
     if($time =='m'){
          $nmr = $nmr*60*1000;
     }else if($time =='s'){
          $nmr = $nmr*1000;
     } echo("<script LANGUAGE='JavaScript'> window.alert('Auto refresh was 
reset!');  window.history.go(-1);</script>");
}
}?>
```

**source code for form get_data.php**

```
<?php include ("process.php"); ?>
<?php echo $nmr; ?>
```

the value from variable `__$nmr__` is empty.

please help me,thanks.

Comment: Your form action is pointing to other file? should it be `get_data.php`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your code I think your problem is the form `action` is pointing to wrong file

it should be

```
<form action="get_data.php" method="POST" >
    <select id="selectbasic" name="time" class="input100">
    <option value="not" selected>-choose-< /option>
    <option value="m">Minut< /option>
    <option value="s">Second< /option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" name="field" id="time" />
    <button type="submit">Time </button>
</form>
```

Keep in mind this code assume that `get_data.php` is in same folder as `input.php`

Comment: sorry my typo, the action must be process.php, i send value from input.php to process.php,  so how i get value from $nmr variable at file get_data.php?

Comment: putting `get_data.php` as action would enable you to get the value of `$nmr` in `get_data.php`. The reason you cant get `$nmr` from `get_data.php` is because it never be called at all

Answer (score 0):

You can submit the form to itself and just use the method POST to get the value.

$var =$_POST["time"];

echo $var;